# JPA direct vs soft (ID) references - what's best?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have a medium sized Java application which uses Hibernate/JPA extensively to store data in the back-end to MS SQL Server.  We are looking for advice on using JPA "direct" references or "soft" references.  What's best and why?

I'm still not great at the proper JPA terminology so I probably am using the wrong terms, but the examples below illustrate what I'm referring to.

```
// Direct example
@Entity
public class Org {
  String name;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
  @ManyToOne
  Org org;
  @Basic
  String nameLast;
}

// Soft example
@Entity
public class Org {
  @Basic
  String ID;
  @Basic
  String name;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Basic
  String nameLast;
  @Basic
  String orgID; // Org.ID value
}
```

Our code originally used almost all direct references.  This took tremendous amounts of time to carefully handle referenced entities being updated in different parts of the code resulting in hibernate exceptions due to unexpected entity changes.  I can't remember the exact exceptions.  There where painful cases of hibernate "stale entity" exceptions.  There where problems when deleting entities referenced by other entities.

Eventually the code base reached a point where it usually worked, but only after extensive testing and debug. The code was very fragile though.  When we added new @Entity classes or changed references, things got ugly fast.

Eventually we had enough and switched to the soft reference model.  After some conversion pain we have reached a point of stability.  The code is much more robust and we see few db related bugs.

The downside to soft references (for us) are:

- We sometimes have dangling references.  In the above example, if an Employee entry has an orgID = "ABC123" and Org "ABC123" is deleted, the Employee entry is not updated.  For us this isn't terribly bad, just not ideal.
- We can't do sort/joins on complex entities with soft references.  If we want to sort the Employee table via Criteria we can't sort based on the Org.name value. This limits the ability of our frontend GUI to sort on such complex entities.  We use lazy-loading between the db and the front-end so its not feasible to have the front-end sort the data.

We would love to hear what the best practices are and any advice from those of you who work on medium to large JPA based applications.

Comment: Well, if you follow DDD, then the rule of thumb would be to use direct references within aggregate roots, and what you call soft references whenever one aggregate references another. The reason why this is the recommended approach is, of course, that (1) aggregate roots group domain objects that change together, and enforcing integrity is easier with direct references, and (2) conversely, isolating aggregate roots from one another is more convenient with 'soft references', preventing code from 'reaching over' to another aggregate

Comment: What is "DDD"?  So I should use a mix of direct and soft refs. It sounds like there's murky choices from this approach but I suppose we can use direct refs on those classes that we want the Criteria sorting on and use soft refs otherwise.  Still some of the classes we would want to use direct refs on have a dozen or so refs so its a real risk going back to direct refs even in limited scope.

Comment: DDD stands for 'domain driven design'

Comment: Thank you @crizzis for the DDD reference.  I went off and read "Implementing Domain Driven Design" by Vaughn and that really helped my understanding.  It's interesting that my "soft" reference is similar to Reference Identities in the IDDD book.  I will move towards the Ref Ident approach going forward.  If you want to post this as an Answer I will endorse.

Comment: Thanks and I'm glad I could be of assistance. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow DDD, then the rule of thumb would be to use direct references within aggregate roots, and what you call soft references whenever one aggregate references another.

The reason why this is the recommended approach is, of course, that:

- Aggregate roots group domain objects that change together, and enforcing integrity is easier with direct references
- Conversely, isolating aggregate roots from one another is more convenient with 'soft references', preventing code from 'reaching over' to another aggregate